# arc diff(Arcanist) failing with env: php: No such file or directory

Tags: php, phabricator, arcanist

After upgrading to macOS Monterey Arcanist commands like arc diff are failing with the following error

```
env: php: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step1

```
brew install php@7.4
ln -s /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

if u get an error on the step 1 run this

```
xcode-select --install
```